# Javascript - How to combine 2 strings so that the result is the name of an existing variable - not just a new string..?

Tags: javascript, variables

Been searching for an answer for this but it's somewhat difficult to search for due to the commonality of the keywords involved!

I would like to be able to call a specific global variable, that contains a number, depending on which variable (containing a string) was passed to the function. So like:

```
var thing1value = 5;
var thing2value = 2;
var thing3value = 8;

function dosomething(whichthing) {
  var x = whichthing + "value";
  return x;
}

dosomething(thing2);
```

would return 2

But I'm not sure how to do this without x becoming a string named "thing2value" instead of the contents of the thing2value variable.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the eval function.

Comment: Or, as an alternative, store the values you are currently storing into variables into an object, so that you can simply use the string as a key to obtain the value

Comment: @Russ No, no, no, no, no! `eval()` is evil and there is hardly a valid use case for it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with variable names (unless you use `eval()`, which you never should). Instead, you can set up object keys that act as variables and then pass strings to the object to obtain the key value.

```js
let things = {
  thing1value:5,
  thing2value:2,
  thing3value:8
}

function dosomething(whichthing) {
  var x = whichthing + "value";
  return things[x];
}

console.log(dosomething("thing2"));
```

**Understanding lexical scope is the key to truly understanding JavaScript.** Global variables are rarely needed and if they truly are, creating a namespace for them will lessen the chances of naming collisions. [The Module Pattern](https://medium.com/technofunnel/data-hiding-with-javascript-module-pattern-62b71520bddd) is widely used to mitigate this exact situation. You could actually write all of your code within the module. In the following, an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is used to implement a form of the pattern:

```js
// By wrapping an anonymous function in parenthesis you
// turn a function declaration into an expression. And,
// the fact that it's an anonymous function means no
// Global variable exists
(function(){

  // Functions create "scope". What's declared within
  // a function is generall not available to higher 
  // scopes unless the function returns something or
  // the function binds a function to a longer-lived
  // object (i.e. a callback), creating a closure
  
  //  YOU COULD PUT ALL THE SCRIPT FOR THE ENTIRE
  //  PAGE IN THIS AREA AND IT WILL ALL BE VISIBLE
  //  TO EACH OTHER, BUT NOT TO THE GLOBAL SCOPE.
  
  
  // This variable is now accessible everywhere inside
  // of the anonymous parent function, but not outside 
  // of it
  let someVariable = "foo";
  
  function a(){
    someVariable += " bar";
  }
  
  function b(){
    someVariable += " baz";  
  }
  
  a();
  console.log(someVariable);
  
  b();
  console.log(someVariable);  
  
})(); // The () at the end invokes the expression
```

Comment: Sorry I did forget to add before that your answer here is clearly the better solution, thank you.  It ends up being cleaner and requiring less code, as I can just turn one variable into another with variable[key] = "data".  Instead of creating a new variable to = window[thing + key] and then using that new variable.  Question though - I still need to this object to be global, so that it can be called by multiple functions and retain its value throughout - so is that not also "bad" like the other solution, in that they both are using global variables?

Comment: @JackChandelier You don't need a variable to be Global to be able to be called by more than one function, you only need to define a wider scope. That's my point, there is rarely a case when Globals are needed, you just need to understand scope and how to create it. I will update my answer to show how you can use the "Module Pattern" to solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: @JackChandelier Also, don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer, by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I did vote but my votes don't count yet as I don't have enough rep.  Didn't know about the check mark though, checked.  I still don't fully understand how to give a wider scope to a variable.  Ideally I'd like my "global" variable to have the scope of the page they're written on, only.  As the only potential collisions would be with external plug-ins.

Comment: @JackChandelier You could follow the pattern I've shown in my second example and place all the JavaScript for your page inside of the outer anonymous function. Lexical scope means that something's scope is dependent on where it was declared. If you declare a variable in a function, it's scope is that function. If you declare other functions within that function, they too will have the same scope and therefore will be accessible to each other.

Comment: AHH.. Sorry I missed the "entire page" part (despite it being in all caps).  Thank you!  What an easy solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Variables are really just key/values of an object. If your example is in the browser, then your global variables are in the `window` scope. So you can access them by string name like so:

```
var thing1value = 5;
var thing2value = 2;
var thing3value = 8;

function dosomething(whichthing) {
  var x = window[whichthing + "value"];
  return x;
}

console.log(dosomething("thing2"));
```

Comment: Yeah, but now you're relying on Global variables, which isn't really a tenable solution.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes I agree, but this is a very important feature of JavaScript to understand. I am tempted to edit, but I think I will leave it as is. Your answer solves the problem in a much more professional way though.

Comment: You really should edit the answer and point out that you are just showing a concept, but something that shouldn't be done in practice. So many users here are new to development that when they see anything that works, they just use it without understanding if it's good or bad.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with relying on global variables?  The variables I'm calling with this function are global..

Comment: @JackChandelier Global variables should always be avoided if possible in any programming language because they tend to cause inadvertent naming collisions as code changes and grows. Depending on the language, memory consumption can be an issue as well because the variable stays in memory longer than is necessary. In general, the best practice is to always create variables with the smallest scope needed to solve the problem and only expand the scope as necessary (cont.)....

Comment: @JackChandelier Additionally, in JavaScript in particular, a Global variable essentially creates a new property on the Global object, which in a browser is `window`. This presents a particular danger because if you create a global variable that happens to be the same name as an existing `window` property, then you will be overwriting that property without even knowing it, potentially damaging the functionality of the `window` object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Gotcha.  That makes sense.  I am only using global variables when needed here, at least I think?  I am coding a board game, so there are a lot of global and local variables..

Comment: @JackChandelier With all respect, there's rarely a need for Global variables. There is a very common pattern in JavaScript called the "module" pattern that encapsulates everything you do so that no Globals are made or needed.

Comment: @JackChandelier Some basics on the topic [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/we-need-to-minimize-the-use-of-global-variables-in-javascript-cafd5dc69b79).

Comment: Okay I read that link but didn't really see an alternative solution.  What do I do when I have several different functions that rely on the same variables?

Also I'm coding a board game for personal use, from scratch with no libraries. The only chance it will have of global variables being overwritten is from third party browser plugins. If that's the case, we'll disable them.

Again, unless you can give me a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate was the word I was looking for!  With that I was able to search properly and find this solution:

newVar = window[varName + "string"]

Comment: I typed the answer to my own question before any of the responses were posted.  Or at least before I refreshed the page and saw any replies.